# What is "at" used to express in each case?

Tags: prepositions

1.I want to succeed at life.
2.I want to win at life.
3. I want to flourish at life.
4. I want to do well at life.
5.I don't want to fail at life.

6.I want to succeed at love.
7.I want to win at love.
8.I want to do well at love.
9.I don't want to fail at love.

10.‎I was failing at my effort to make peace.

11.I want to succeed at my dream.
12.I don't want to fail at my dream.

I have found "at life", "at love", "at my effort", "at my dream" often used in such cases as above.
By the way, I wonder what "at" means in each case because "at" doesn't mean the same thing  . 
Specifically speaking, I mean, from 1 to 10, "at" seems to be used to express the moment of being alive (=at life), the moment of being in love with (=at love), the moment of making my effort (=at my effort), but from 11 to 12, "at" seems to be used to express the goal(=my dream) that the subject(=I) wants to achieve.

I wonder whether I'm right.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Most if not all of your examples would more naturally use the preposition ***in***, not ***at***.

Comment: with succeed: we succeed **at something**.